# Picking Unique Balls from a Bin

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, solution-verification

Problem:

> We have a bin with 5 red balls, 7 green balls, and 9 blue balls. We
>   draw 3 balls out of the bin, without replacement. What is the probability that no two of the three balls have the same color?

My Answer:

Note that the probability of no two balls having the same color is equivalent to all three balls having different colors. The probability of this event is
$$\frac{5}{21} \cdot \frac{7}{20} \cdot \frac{9}{19} = \frac {3}{76}$$
Because on the first  step we want to pick a red ball, which has probability of $\frac 5{21}$, on the second step we want to pick a green ball, and on the third step we want to pick a blue ball. The order in which we pick the balls doesn't matter, which is reflected in the (associative) multiplication: $5/21 \cdot 7/20 = 7/21 \cdot 5/20$, etc.

Is this right? I'm sceptical of my answer. I wrote a script to test my answer, and it appears that the probability should be just a little under $\frac 1 4$, which sounds much more reasonable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to multiply your answer by $6$.

Your probability is for a red ball followed by a green ball followed by a blue ball.  The probability of a green ball followed by a blue ball followed by a red ball would be $\displaystyle \frac{7}{21} \cdot \frac{9}{20} \cdot \frac{5}{19}$ which is also $ \dfrac {3}{76}$ and altogether there are $3!=6$ possible orderings.

This would give $\dfrac{9}{38}\approx 0.2368$ as the probability of three different colours in any order.

Comment: Why? $\phantom{}$

Comment: Because you could pick the three colors in any order.  Your calculation assumes that you must pick red first, but picking green, blue, red still gets one of each color.

Comment: @RossMillikan I thought that didn't matter because multiplication is associative (as I commented: $5/21 \cdot 7/20 = 7/21 \cdot 5/20$). I understand that $6=3!$ which is equal to the possible number of orderings on the three colors, I'm just looking for a justification.

Comment: The probabilities of each order are the same but you do need to add them up.  Suppose you had only one ball of each colour and you draw without replacement:   the probability that no two of the three balls drawn have the same colour is clearly $1$, which might also be written as $\displaystyle 6 \left( \frac{1}{3} \cdot \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{1}\right)$

Comment: Ah, right. The symmetry of the cases had caused me to overlook adding them up. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Another way to get this would be to take $\displaystyle\frac{7\cdot9\cdot5}{\binom{21}{3}}$,

since there are $7\cdot9\cdot5$ ways to choose 3 balls having different colors

and $\dbinom{21}{3}$ ways to choose 3 balls without restrictions.